# How do I select certain columns from Python?

Tags: python, select, subset, na, drop

I must be doing a very basic mistake. I am trying to select only certain columns from a dataframe, dropping the na rows. I also am supposed to reset the row index after removing the rows.
This is what my dataset looks like

```
     CRIM     ZN     INDUS  CHAS   NOX    ...  TAX  PTRATIO  B        LSTAT  MEDV                                        
0    0.00632  18.0   2.31   0.0    0.538  ...  296     15.3  396.90   4.98   24.0
1    0.02731   0.0   7.07   0.0    0.469  ...  242     17.8  396.90   9.14   21.6
2    0.02729   0.0   7.07   0.0    0.469  ...  242     17.8  392.83   4.03   34.7
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
F = HousingData.dropna(subset = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS'])
```

this first attempt just gives no output

```
HousingData.select("CRIM").show("CRIM")
```

this one gives the error message AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select'

cheers!

Comment: Try `F=HousingData[['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS']].dropna()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few problems. first when you use `dropna` you can indicate the parameter `inplace=True`, or work with the output of the method which in your code you named `F`.

Second I do belive that you are used to R and not python, whilst in R you select rows using `select` in python  do not; you can use either `HousingData.loc[:, my_colum]` or  `HousingData["my_colum"]` here there is more [info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) for pandas dataframe indexing

Finally, I'm not sure what you what to do with `show()` but is also not valid for python you can use `plot`, `head` or `values` ...

```py
HousingData.dropna(subset=['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS'], inplace=True)
HousingData["CRIM"].plot() # visualize the first 5 values
# HousingData["CRIM"].head() # visualize the first 5 values

# if you don't use inplace=True
F = HousingData.dropna(subset=['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS'])
F["CRIM"].plot()
```